# can't get value of object from observable data

Tags: angular, mongodb, object, observable

I have this data in mongoDB (important field "period" is red border) :

[image]
I have this function that get some data:

```
myFunction(): void {
this.mySubscription = this.myObservable
.pipe(
  map(data => data
    .map(item => item.period))
)
.subscribe((res) => {
  for (const entry of res) {
    console.log('entry: ', entry);
  }
});
```

At page display, i got this output in the console :

> [image: Blockquote]

but if i want to get the same way, the **startDate** inside 'period' object i got this error in my .ts file:

> property startDate does not exists on type {}:

[image]

Any help on this ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't know whether it will have startDate. You can get rid of that error/warning by adding any type

so it would be `(diapuse:any)`